# Variável interferindo no valor de outra váriavel

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Boa tarde Srs.

Estou enfrentando um problema que nunca vi antes, abaixo tenho uma *view* mapeada no EF com fluent

```
var viewRelatorio = db.view.where(ra.DataBruta.Month == mesAno.Month).toList();
```

tenho dois dicionários que irão interagir com os dados dessa view

```
var rel1 = new Dictionary<int, Relatorio>();
var relItemVirada = new Dictionary<int, Relatorio>();

var relatorio = new Relatorio>();
var eventoFinal = false
```

faço a leitura da view para iteração com os dicionários

```
foreach (var item in viewRelatorio)
{
  rel1.Add(i, item);                                       
  if (item.HorarioInicial.StartsWith("23") &&  item.HorarioFinal.StartsWith("00"))
  {
    relatorio = item;
    relatorio.HorarioFinal = "235959";
    relItemVirada.Add(i, relatorio);        
  }
  i++;
}
```

O que acontece é que toda vez que eu mudo o valor em relatorio.HorarioFinal ele muda o valor original em item que não sofre nenhum tipo de mudança, gostaria de saber o que pode ser isso ?

Ja tentei interagir de diversas formas, laços diferentes, diretamente no item, sempre que mexo em um item afeta o próximo ou vice e versa

segue o mapeamento fluent

```
public RelatorioConfiguration()
        : base("name=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databaseInstance"].ToString())
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var relatorio = modelBuilder.Entity<Relatorio>();

        relatorio.ToTable("view_Relatorio");

        relatorio.HasKey(p => new {p.DataBruta, p.HorarioInicial});
        relatorio.Property(p => p.Ano);
        relatorio.Property(p => p.Classificacao);
        relatorio.Property(p => p.DataBruta);
        relatorio.Property(p => p.HorarioFinal);
        relatorio.Property(p => p.HorarioInicial);
    }

    public DbSet<Relatorio> Relatorio { get; set; }
```

Comment: não sei se tem a ver com isso, mais pode ser o ChangeTracker do Entity entendendo que você está editando um item da tabela, tente usar o 'db.view.AsNoTracking().Where(ra.DataBruta.Month == mesAno.Month).toList();' desta forma desabilita o ChangeTracker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, seu problema não está no EF mas sim pelo fato de classes serem por referência e não por valor no .Net.

Vou me atentar a esta pergunta sua:

> O que acontece é que toda vez que eu mudo o valor em relatorio.HorarioFinal ele **muda o valor original em item** que não sofre nenhum tipo de mudança, gostaria de saber o que pode ser isso ?

Vendo seu código `relatorio = item;` quando você atribui "item" a uma uma outra variável "relatorio" você não "copia" o item mas sim apenas uma referência e sendo assim as duas variáveis neste momento apontam para o mesmo objeto. Logo se você alterar uma propriedade de "relatorio", vai alterar em "item" também. Por isso esse código `relatorio.HorarioFinal = "235959"` está alterando também o valor de "item.HorarioFinal".

Para exemplificar eu fiz um exemplo no DotNetFiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/wjaaAm.

Uma solução é realizar um clone do objeto e uma das maneiras de fazer isso é usando o BinaryFormatter, segue um exemplo de código de uma extension abaixo:

```
    public static T DeepClone<T>(this T source) where T : class
    {
        using (Stream cloneStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            formatter.Serialize(cloneStream, source);
            cloneStream.Position = 0;
            T clone = (T)formatter.Deserialize(cloneStream);

            return clone;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: eu imaginei que fosse algo semelhante a isso, mas como seria a copia do item efetivamente e não o apontamento para a referencia ?

Comment: @Leo editei minha resposta para conter uma possível solução.